# Separating fact from fiction, how to get from this radar image to this GIF?

Tags: asteroid, imaging, radar, near-earth-object, delay-doppler

The NBC News article [Mile-wide asteroid and its tiny moon to zoom past Earth this weekend; Dubbed 1999 KW4, the "binary" space rock will skim past our planet harmlessly at a distance of 3 million miles.](https://www.nbcnews.com/mach/science/mile-wide-asteroid-its-tiny-moon-zoom-past-earth-weekend-ncna1009381) shows the animated GIF below, and links to the Asteroid Tracker page [1999 KW4](https://asteroidtracker.lco.global/asteroid/14/).

Images there are credited to

> Dr. Steven Ostro et al. - http://echo.jpl.nasa.gov/~ostro/kw4/

but that link is dead. They also link to Wikimedia for sources

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1288618
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=560247

Without the link to Ostro et al (which Wikimedia also links to) there's no way to track this down.

How did scientists go from radar images to this very detailed GIF of two bodies orbiting each other, with such detail of the huge equatorial ridge on alpha?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably another victim of NASA's consolidating and messing up its web sites.

Comment: I just climbed the tree from that broken link and ended up here: https://echo.jpl.nasa.gov/ There's a link from that page to https://echo.jpl.nasa.gov/asteroids/1999KW4/1999kw4.html which appears to be what you are looking for. This is very far out of my wheelhouse so I won't be writing anything up on this.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Jackpot! That's beautiful stuff, thank you sir.

Comment: I considered directly asking Dr. Ostro, but unfortunately he has passed on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_J._Ostro

Comment: @OrganicMarble I wonder if you would considered expanding or at least stretching your wheelhouse? Still no answers.